# The complex number z is given by z = (1+3i)/(p+qi), where p and q are real and p > q > 0. Given that Arg(z) = pi/4, show that p - 2q = 0.

Tags: complex-numbers

First method I used:

$$ z = \frac{\sqrt{10} cis (\arctan(3))}{\sqrt{p^2 + q^2} cis (\arctan (\frac qp))} $$
$$ \arctan 3 - \arctan \frac qp = \frac \pi4 $$
$$ - \arctan \frac qp = \frac \pi4 - \arctan 3 $$
$$ \arctan \frac qp = -\frac \pi4 + \arctan 3 $$
$$ \frac qp = \tan (-\frac \pi4 + \arctan 3) $$
$$ \frac qp = \frac 12 $$
$$ p = 2q $$
$$ p - 2q = 0 $$

Second method from book, which I then also used:

$$ z = \frac {(1+3i)(p-qi)}{(p+qi)(p-qi)} $$
$$ z = \frac {p + (3p-q)i + 3q}{p^2+q^2} $$

$ Arg(z) = \frac {\pi}{4} $ so $ z = |z| \cos (\frac {\pi}{4}) + i|z| \sin (\frac{\pi}{4}).$
Hence, Re(z) = Im(z)
$$ 1 = \frac {3p-q}{p+3q}$$
$$ p+3q=3p-q$$
$$ -2p = -4q$$
$$ p = 2q$$
$$p - 2q = 0$$

Here I have three questions: 
1. What is the significance of $p > q > 0$?  
2. Is my first method wrong or not preferred? 
3. For the second method, what if the given argument was so Re(z) ≠ Im(z)?

Comment: What is the !=  in your third question?  As for the book's answer, the real and imaginary parts of $ \ z \ $ are equal _because_ the argument is $ \ \frac{\pi}{4} \ $ .  So I'm not clear about what you're asking there.

Comment: What if the argument was something else?

Comment: The book approach uses the equality of the real and imaginary parts to set up the equation $ \ p \ + \ 3q \ = \ 3p \ - \ q \ $ , from the numerator of $ \ z \ $ . (This is essentially what **lab bhattacharjee** is showing below.) Were the argument some other value, we would have to insert a factor for the tangent of $ \ Arg \ z \ $ other than $ \ 1 \ $ into the book's equation.

Comment: What book did you get it from?

Answer (score 1):

$$\dfrac{1+3i}{p+iq}=\dfrac{(1+3i)(p-iq)}{p^2+q^2}=\dfrac{p+3q+i(3p-q)}{p^2+q^2}$$

Now using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation), Arg$(z)=\arctan\dfrac{3p-q}{p+3q}$ if $p+3q>0$

$\arctan\dfrac{3p-q}{p+3q}=\dfrac\pi4\implies\dfrac{3p-q}{p+3q}=\tan\dfrac\pi4=1$

Answer (score 1):

We can consider the locations of the numerator and denominator on the complex plane as vectors $ \ \langle \ 1, \ 3 \ \rangle \ $ and  $ \ \vec{w} \ = \ \langle \ p, \ q \ \rangle \ $ .  Since $ \ Arg \ z \ = \ \frac{\pi}{4} \ $ , this represents the included angle between the vectors ( $ \ \langle \ 1, \ 3 \ \rangle \ $ being counter-clockwise from $ \ \vec{w} \ $ ) , so we have the scalar ("dot") product

$$   \langle \ 1, \ 3 \ \rangle \ \cdot \ \vec{w} \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{10} \ | \ \vec{w} \ | \ \cos \frac{\pi}{4} $$
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ p \ + \ 3q \ \ = \ \ \sqrt{5} \ \sqrt{p^2 \ + \ q^2} $$

$$ \Rightarrow \  \ p^2 \ + \ 6 \ p \ q \ + \ 9 \ q^2 \ \ = \ \ 5 \ (p^2 \ + \ q^2 ) $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 2 \ p^2 \ - \ 3 \ p \ q \ - \ 2 \ q^2 \ = \ 0 \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (2 \ p \ + \ q) \ ( p \ - \ 2q ) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $$

We may reject the factor solution $ \ 2 \ p \ + \ q \ \ = \ \ 0 \ $ , as this put $ \ \vec{w} \ $ counter-clockwise from $ \langle \ 1, \ 3 \ \rangle \ $ (which would give us $ \ Arg \ z \ = \ - \frac{\pi}{4} \ $ ) .  This approach spares us the algebra of working with conjugate factors.

As to your first question, the imposed condition keeps both complex numbers in the first quadrant (and is what lets us toss out the $ \ 2 \ p \ + \ q \  $   solution.  Your first method looks to be correct. There is not any special reason to prefer any of the methods discussed here over others. Yours is a more "geometric" method than the one the book uses.

Answer (score 1):

> Given is:
>
> - $$\text{z}=\frac{1+3i}{p+qi}$$
> - $$p\space\wedge\space q\in\mathbb{R}$$
> - $$p>q>0\to p>0,0<q<p$$
> - $$\arg\left[\text{z}\right]=\arg\left[\frac{1+3i}{p+qi}\right]=\frac{\pi}{4}$$

---

Now, step-by-step:

- The number $\text{z}$:

$$\text{z}=\frac{1+3i}{p+qi}=\frac{(1+3i)(p-qi)}{(p+qi)(p-qi)}=\frac{(1+3i)(p-qi)}{\left|p+qi\right|^2}=\frac{(1+3i)(p-qi)}{p^2+q^2}=$$
$$\frac{p+3q+(3p-q)i}{p^2+q^2}=\frac{p+3q}{p^2+q^2}+\frac{(3p-q)i}{p^2+q^2}$$

- The argument of the number $\text{z}$:

$$\arg\left[\text{z}\right]=\frac{\pi}{4}\Longleftrightarrow\arg\left[\frac{1+3i}{p+qi}\right]=\frac{\pi}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\arg\left[1+3i\right]-\arg\left[p+qi\right]=\frac{\pi}{4}\Longleftrightarrow\arctan(3)-\arg\left[p+qi\right]=\frac{\pi}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$-\arg\left[p+qi\right]=\frac{\pi}{4}-\arctan(3)\Longleftrightarrow\arg\left[p+qi\right]=\arctan(3)-\frac{\pi}{4}\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\arctan\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)=\arctan(3)-\frac{\pi}{4}\Longleftrightarrow\tan\left(\arctan\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)\right)=\tan\left(\arctan(3)-\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\Longleftrightarrow$$
$$\frac{q}{p}=\frac{1}{2}\Longleftrightarrow p-2q=0$$

Comment: This "answer" makes unnecessary circles until the previous-to-last equivalence sign, where one suddenly jumps without justification to the conclusion. I guess any mathematical question can be "solved" this way.